# Does AWS KMS key rotation automatically re-encrypt SecureString values stored in SSM parameter store?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm, amazon-kms

I have a customer managed key encrypting secret parameters as SecureString in SSM Parameter store. I'm deciding whether I should allow AWS to automatically rotate those keys. It would be nice to not have to worry about re-encrypting the secrets manually.

This is how I set the parameters:

```
aws ssm put-parameter \
            --region $region \
            --name "$name" \
            --value "$value" \
            --type "SecureString" \
            --key-id "$keyId" \
            --overwrite;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Parameter Store itself doesn't have automatic key rotation service. But, they do provide another service for this, i.e., Secrets Manager.

Quote from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/integrating_parameterstore.html).

> Parameter Store doesn't provide automatic rotation services for stored secrets. Instead, Parameter Store enables you to store your secret in Secrets Manager, and then reference the secret as a Parameter Store parameter.